# set clicklistner on imageview

Tags: android, imageview, expandablelistview

I'm working with expandable listview. In that I need to use click-able imageview. I've tried following but not working. It gives null pointer exception.

here is my xml and listview adapter. I need to put click event on the imageview. from normal activity onclicklistner works perfact, but gives error if you put that in ExpandableListActivity.

Thanks in advance..

```
public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
{
//    static final String parent_node[] = { "grey", "blue", "yellow", "red" };

String parent_node[];

static final String shades[][] = {
  {
    "lightgrey","#D3D3D3",
    "dimgray","#696969",
    "sgi gray 92","#EAEAEA"
  }, {},
  {
    "dodgerblue 2","#1C86EE",
    "steelblue 2","#5CACEE",
    "powderblue","#B0E0E6"
  }, {}
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   


    LayoutInflater group_inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View group_layout = group_inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);

    ImageView img_call = (ImageView)group_layout.findViewById(R.id.imgcall);

    img_call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {           
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
      {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "clicked...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }); 

SimpleExpandableListAdapterWithEmptyGroups expListAdapter =
            new SimpleExpandableListAdapterWithEmptyGroups(
                this,
                createGroupList(),                      
                R.layout.group_row,                     
                new String[] { "colorName" },           
                new int[] { R.id.groupname },           
                createChildList(),                      
                R.layout.child_row,                     
                new String[] { "shadeName", "rgb" },    
                new int[] { R.id.childname, R.id.rgb }  
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );}
```

And my groupview xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/expander_group"
    android:id="@+id/explist_indicator"
    android:layout_width="35px"
    android:layout_height="35px"/>


<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/contact_thumbnail"
    android:id="@+id/img_contact_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/groupname"
    android:layout_width="190px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="30px"
    android:textSize="16px"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgcall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/call"
    android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**
Now NullPointerException problem is solved. But I came up new problem that onclicklistner is not working. No Toast or anything else written in that section doesn't execute. I debug program and found that code does not return on onclicklistner when imageview get clicked.

Any idea??

Comment: For a ListView, you have to feed it with an `Adapter`(the data for the ListView to display), from your code I can't see one. If the imageview you mentioned is the listview item, you may simply override `onItemClick()` for the ListView, you don't need to set `OnClickListener` for each item.

Comment: Post your `main.xml` layout here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, hope fully it should work. Just add two line in your xml inside imageview and then write a function to listen the button click in your activity class:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgcall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/call"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:onClick="onClickHandler"/>
```

And in your activity class :

```
public void onClickHandler (View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgcall:
            // do what ever you want here ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you.. this is working.. but cant understand why inline clicklistner is not working???